# Operator Overloading : Why This Code Is Not Working ?

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

As you can see I am trying to add 7 days to "Days" to Class "MyAge", but it gives me
one error:

> no matching function for call to MyAge::MyAge(int , int&, int&)

Why this is happening?
While you answer this question try to be more noob specific.

Sorry for my bad english, I am an Indian. here is my code.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyAge
{
private:  
    int Days;
    int Months;
    int Years;
    int DaysToAdd;
public:
    void SetAge(int InputDays,int InputMonths,int InputYears)
    {
        Years= InputYears;
        Months=InputMonths;
        Days=InputDays;
    }

    MyAge operator + (int Add)
    {
        MyAge Blah (Days + Add,Months,Years);
        return Blah;
    }

    void Display()
    { 
        cout <<"Your age after increment is"<<Years<<"years"<<Months<<"Months"<<Days<<"Days";
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyAge BirthDay;
    BirthDay.SetAge(10,11,19);
    MyAge NameDay(BirthDay+7);
    NameDay.Display();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to call a 3-parameter constructor, but you don't have one. You could add it, or change the implementation of `operator +` like this:

```
MyAge operator + (int Add)
{
  MyAge Blah;
  Blah.SetAge(Days + Add, Months, Years);
  return Blah;
}
```